# How to know if optional argument was passed?

Tags: python, argparse

For example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
parser.add_argument('k', help='k index', type=int)
parser.add_argument('j', help='j', type=int, nargs='?')
```

I need to know if argument `j` was given or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object) object returned by [`parser.parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) will have a `j` attribute assigned to the `int` provided (if one was provied), or `None` (if it wasn't provided).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
parser.add_argument('k', help='k index', type=int)
parser.add_argument('j', help='j', type=int, nargs='?')
for inputs in (['5'], ['5', '2']):
    args = parser.parse_args(inputs)
    if args.j is not None:
       print("got a j")
    else:
       print("No j")
```

Output:

```
No j
got a j
```